# Port forwarding with multiple WAN default routes in OpenWRT

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, openwrt

I have an OpenWrt setup with multiple WAN connections, and a DNAT port redirect that provides access to a server in my LAN. I want my server to be **accessible on both WAN connections** simultaneously.

I am not using any load balancing package like [mwan3](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/multiwan/mwan3) as I need no load balancing setup for outgoing traffic. Instead, I have **multiple gateways** in my routing table with different metric values. All such networks are added in a **single firewall zone** `wan` in the OpenWrt firewall configuration.

##### Example route table:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip route
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1  metric 5
default via 10.0.2.1 dev eth2  metric 8
...
```

I get a simple failover setup with the above configuration, as the default route for *10.0.1.1* is removed when the link goes down.

##### Example port forward rule:

```
config redirect
        option name 'Server'
        option target 'DNAT'
        list proto 'tcp'
        option src 'wan'
        option src_dport '1234'
        option dest 'lan'
        option dest_ip '192.168.1.234'
        option dest_port '5678'
```

However my port forwarding is broken with this setup:

- When single default route is present in the table:

  - Port forwarding always works when only one WAN connection is active
- When multiple default routes are present:

  - Port forwarding works when the server is contacted through the gateway with the lowest metric value (the highest default route in above example: *10.0.1.1*)
  - Port forwarding doesn't work when the server is contacted through a gateway with a higher metric value (*10.0.2.1* in above example) - a *connection timed out* error occurs instead

This behaviour made me think that probably the returning traffic from the server is not being sent to the same gateway from where it is originating - it is instead being sent to the lowest metric gateway.
Am I correct? Is there any way to check this?

---

On further searching, I found [this page](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wan/multiple_wan_multiple_routers) in the OpenWrt wiki that talks about doing something similar but using multiple routers, however the page seems to be incomplete.

- How does one implement the mentioned connection marking solution in OpenWrt? Will it work for UDP, ICMP traffic as well?
- Is there any other possible solution that does not involve using connection marking or *mwan3* and VLANs?

Comment: It's a *routing* problem and policy routing ("routing rule" is mentioned multiple times in your link) using the command `ip rule` and routing tables with `ip route ... table ...`. Then this problem will require marks anyway, to use conntrack flows as "database". Before solving this as an OpenWRT configuration problem, you have first to understand it as a Linux problem, then try to figure out how to integrate this within OpenWRT.  Here's an answer I made on UL SE for a similar problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573858/iptables-multiwan-and-portforwarding-port-redirection/setup.sh

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the detailed answer on UL StackExchange. I will try to implement a solution using *iptables* marking and multiple routing tables first, and then try to port the same to OpenWrt configuration.